# Элементы массива

Tags: java, массивы

Идея такая: есть массив без емкости. Кол-во элементов массива вводит сам пользователь. Теперь, нужно сделать так, чтобы значение каждого массива задавал юзер.

Предполагаю, это может быть реализовано с помощью цикла `for`. Но я не знаю, как сделать поочередный ввод значения каждого элемента массива.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
   System.out.println("Введите объем массива, как целое число"); 
   int User0 = scan.nextInt();
   int [] Int = new int [User0]; 
   System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Int));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Введите объем массива, как целое число: ");
int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println();

if (arraySize > 0) {
    int[] array = new int[massiveSize];
    for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < arraySize; ++itemNumber) {
        System.out.print("Введите " + itemNumber + " элемент массива: ");
        array[itemNumber] = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```